# Is it okay to reroute this water heater line?

Tags: leak, heater, slab

[image: reroute at tributary near manifold capped]The slab under hot water heater 3/4" hot manifold was leaking, so I decided to have plumber reroute through the attic.
The 3/4" copper that supplies hot water to bath manifold through the slab is cut off, the 3/4" manifold at the bath slab is also cut and capped off.
A new 3/4" copper connects water heater's hot supply over the attic, but due to tight space at the bath manifold on slab, its 3/4" copper is cut and capped off. The attic 3/4" copper is reduced to 1/2" and soldered into a 1/2" tributary branched from the bath 3/4" manifold which already branches to 4 other 1/2" copper under slab that supply 4 sinks and 2 tubs.
My concern is the hot supply from water heater 3/4" reduced to 1/2" then flows back to bath manifold whose 3/4" copper is capped, then distributed to faucets through 1/2" under slab, is it safe reroute this way?
Will the 1/2" tributary pipe where hot supply joins break or leak in a few years because it is used like a 3/4" artery to distribute hot water?

Comment: pictures would help us understand what your issue is.  If you are concerned that the 3/4 being reduced to 1/2 is too much pressure, that should not be a worry.  Copper when soldered properly can withstand pressure far greater than most water supply systems.

Comment: How do I upload or attach a 2mb jpg file on this forum? What's the email address of this web site so I can email a small jpg file?

Comment: Marking as duplicate of a resubmitted question with a photo [Is it okay to reroute this water heater (picture)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/267940/is-it-okay-to-reroute-this-water-heater-picture). This photo should have been uploaded to that question instead of duplicating questions.